# После генерации файла .apk в eclipse он определяется как зараженный

Tags: android, eclipse

Начал изучать программирование под Android. С помощью eclipse и SDK создаю простейшее приложение типа "Hello, World". Приложение генерируется без ошибок. Получаю .apk файл, который можно установить на телефон и оно работает. Далее загружаю этот  .apk на Google Disk. И вот при попытке скачать с Google Disk'a он определяет мой .apk как зараженный. Воспользовавшись онлайн антивирусом для apk вижу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] .На каком этапе и каким образом в файл .apk добавляется что-то вредоносное? 
P.S. Так было не всегда. Но вот после чего появилась данная проблема - не могу сказать. После очередной загрузки на Google Disk было обнаружено что нет связи (отошел кабель от роутера), и после восстановления связи началось вышеописанное. При создании такого же проекта в AndroidStudio -  все нормально. AS и eclipse используют одну и ту же SDK.

Comment: вы откуда eclipse качали?

Comment: теперь уже точно не вспомню, но вроде бы с www.eclipse.org/downloads... Дело в том что еще вчера такой проблемы не было. Я не могу понять в чем вообще может быть причина.